# Action bar moving down while replacing with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

I am adding a fragment to activity, and then i am replacing that fragment with the second fragment.After replacing the second fragment action bar is slightly moving down like this
[image]

My Activity code

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meetinglist_activity);
    Fragment first_fragment = new FirstFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, first_fragment).commit();
     }
```

Replacing second fragment in the first fragment's button click

```
public class Firstfragment extends Fragment  {


FloatingActionButton new_fab;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View list_view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.meetingslist_fragment,container,false);
    new_fab=(FloatingActionButton)list_view.findViewById(R.id.meeting_new);
    new_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment second_fragment = new SecondFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, second_fragment).commit();
  }
```

Activity layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment's Xml

```
<!--First Layout-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/meeting_new"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


 <!--Second Layout-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I am using  **android.support.v4.app.Fragment;**

I am using Android Studio version2.0 and latest API levels.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your fragment xml ??

Comment: may b its happens Bcoz.. you have included Coordinate layout in First Fragment Layout only ,,, put Coordinate Layout in Activity so it work same for both Fragment

Comment: @UttamPanchasara   yes, that is correct Answer ,Thanks , post your  answer i will give upvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Occurs Bcoz Coordinate Layout In First Fragment Only Put Coordinate Layout in second fragment so it will work same for both Layouts.

Answer (score 8):

Just change this line

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

to

> android:fitsSystemWindows="false"

I'm sure your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

I guess to solve all issues related to actionbar you should use toolbar which is new replacement of old actionbar by Google. You can find tutorial of implementing toolbar at end of the link: http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example